# How to keep data inside a text area after submission?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a text area where i can input text, after the form has been submitted the text from the first field goes to the second output field. Now I have the exact same things on the same page, so input field, submit and output field. What I want is when the either one of the submit buttons have been pressed, the output will stay and not clear out. Here is what I've done so far:

```
<head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <?php

            $inputText = $_GET['FirstText'];
            $InputTextTwo = $_GET['SecondText'];
          ?>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="#" method="GET">
            <textarea cols="50" rows="2" name="FirstText"></textarea>
                <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_firstField" value="FirstField">       
                <br>
            <textarea disabled="yes" cols="50" rows="2" name="SecondOfFirst"><?php echo $inputText;  ?></textarea>
        </form>

        <hr/>

        <form action="#" method="GET">
            <textarea cols="50" rows="2" name="SecondText"></textarea>
                <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_SecondField" value="SecondField">     
                <br>
            <textarea disabled="yes" cols="50" rows="2" name="SecondOfSecond"><?php echo $InputTextTwo;  ?></textarea>

        </form>
    </body>
```

As you can see, when the first submit has been done and I want to do the second one, the first output disappears, and vice versa.

Comment: How many forms are we talking about? Just 2? If just two, then keep the data of the 'other form' in the form, so that you can use those hidden inputs to continually propogate. OR stuff it in _SESSION. OR come up with another way (theres numerous).

Comment: @Randall stuffing it into one same form doesnt essentially work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved your problem. 
The main reason is the two textareas now used different Form. 
So Only one textarea value can submit at once. 
I added temp hidden-input field inside each form and run the code. 
And It's working well now. Please check them.

Tian Yang

```
<html>
<head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <?php
            $inputText = 'asdf';
            $InputTextTwo = 'bbbb';
           if(isset($_GET['FirstText'])){
             $inputText = $_GET['FirstText'];
             $InputTextTwo = $_GET['temp'];
           }
           if(isset($_GET['SecondText'])){
             $InputTextTwo = $_GET['SecondText'];
             $inputText = $_GET['temp'];
           }
          ?>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="#" method="GET">
            <textarea cols="50" rows="2" name="FirstText"></textarea>
                <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_firstField" value="FirstField">       
            <input type="hidden" name="temp" value ="<?php echo $InputTextTwo;  ?>" />
                <br>
            <textarea disabled="yes" cols="50" rows="2" name="SecondOfFirst"><?php echo $inputText;  ?></textarea>
        </form>

        <hr/>

        <form action="#" method="GET">
            <textarea cols="50" rows="2" name="SecondText"></textarea>
                <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_SecondField" value="SecondField">     
            <input type="hidden" name="temp" value ="<?php echo $inputText;  ?>" />
                <br>
            <textarea disabled="yes" cols="50" rows="2" name="SecondOfSecond"><?php echo $InputTextTwo;  ?></textarea>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What if i add somekind of a logic into to the code, so like turn x int 1 and y into 0, then i would need to echo this out with a foreach, how would i get this to be echoed out ? the Logic e.g:   `if(isset($_GET['FirstText'])){
             $inputText = $_GET['FirstText'];
             $InputTextTwo = $_GET['temp'];
      $digits = str_split($digits, 4);
              $ChangeArray = array(
        "" => " ",
          " " => " ",
          "x" => "1",
          "y" => "0",
          );
              foreach ($digits as $val) {
               $ChangeArray[$val];
              }`

Comment: ... By putting $inputText = $inputText . $ChangeArray[$val];in it would only echo out One-part so if the input was  xy it would only output 0

Comment: ...How would i get this echoed out by using your solution?

Comment: What if i add somekind of a logic into to the code, so like turn x int 1 and y into 0, then i would need to echo this out with a foreach, how would i get this to be echoed out ? the Logic e.g:   `if(isset($_GET['FirstText'])){
             $inputText = $_GET['FirstText'];
             $InputTextTwo = $_GET['temp'];
      $digits = str_split($inputText);
              $ChangeArray = array(
        "" => " ",
          " " => " ",
          "x" => "1",
          "y" => "0",
          );
              foreach ($digits as $val) {
               $ChangeArray[$val];
              }`

Comment: Sorry i had a mistake in the first comment and had to write this again since stackOverflow seems to have a very odd system to editing comments..